# Unity || How do I make the area where two images intersect transparent?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, intersection

I'm developing a game, and the main purpose of this game is that the part where the two black shapes overlap when they overlap is transparent.I found a shader over the internet and I'm using it.This shader allows us to assign color to the intersection of two shapes, but I cannot make it transparent.

[image]

```
Shader "Unlit/Stencil"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
        SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Opaque"}
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            Stencil {
                Ref 0
                Comp Equal
                Pass IncrSat
                Fail IncrSat
            }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = fixed4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            Stencil {
                Ref 1
                Comp Less
            }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = fixed4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            Stencil {
                Ref 2
                Comp Less
            }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = fixed4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming these are canvas image types?

Comment: I am using Sprite(2D and UI) image types.

Comment: ok, and will these always be rectangles like in the image above, or will they be more complex shapes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make the overlapping area of two sprites transparent in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726096/how-can-i-make-the-overlapping-area-of-two-sprites-transparent-in-unity)