# How can I make the overlapping area of two sprites transparent in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, buffer, shader

How can I make the overlapping area of two sprites transparent in Unity? Could you write a shader about it? After some research, I learned that I should use stencil buffer, but I don't know how. This is vital to me. I have to complete this school project in 6 days.
Please help .. = (

EXAMPLE IMAGE:

[image]

Comment: You may have accidentally posted this twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59717298/unity-how-do-i-make-the-area-where-two-images-intersect-transparent

Comment: I'm sorry, I asked the question more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, keep in mind this is the first time I'm using stencil so I might have done something less than optimal. But it works with sprites as you requested.

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'

Shader "Sprites/Stencil"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        { 
            "Queue"="Transparent" 
            "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
            "RenderType"="Transparent" 
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha



        Pass
        {
            Stencil {
                Ref 1
                Comp Greater
                Pass replace
                Fail Zero
            }

        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };
            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            };
            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
                return half4(0,0,0,0);
            }
        ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            Stencil {
                Ref 1
                Comp equal
                Pass keep 
            }

        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
                OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
                #endif

                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _AlphaTex;
            float _AlphaSplitEnabled;

            fixed4 SampleSpriteTexture (float2 uv)
            {
                fixed4 color = tex2D (_MainTex, uv);

#if UNITY_TEXTURE_ALPHASPLIT_ALLOWED
                if (_AlphaSplitEnabled)
                    color.a = tex2D (_AlphaTex, uv).r;
#endif //UNITY_TEXTURE_ALPHASPLIT_ALLOWED

                return color;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 c = SampleSpriteTexture (IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
                c.rgb *= c.a;
                return c;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general please post code directly on this page instead of urls. External pages might at any time be removed so the URL and this post would become garbage :)

Comment: @derHugo Even if it's my own Github gist?

Comment: yes .. who can assure that you won't remove it in the future? Some exceptions can be made if it is like 500 lines of code but in general you should put all relevant information in your answer itself

Comment: OK, didn't know that was part of the rules; learn something new every day. I personally hate seeing code here, that's why I usually post it on gist.

Comment: If your answer requires that much code then the question actually wasn't asked very well. Usually StackOverflow is no place for providing entire solutions someone requested but rather is for fixing issues in already existing scripts. Therefore in an answer you usually only need to post the lines that requrie changes ;)